# iPhone simulator Problem delete data

Tags: iphone, ios4, ios-simulator

I have an app the store some data in the keychains. Now I want to re-check if everything works correct but I don't know how I can I delete all data stored by this app in the simulator.
Can someone help me?
Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the applications in your simulator appear in:

> ~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/User/

Simply remove the files you're adding in the applications folder. Each app is give a GUID for the directory name - you may need to look in each one to find out which you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

An app on the simulator can be purged in the same way as an app on a device. Delete it! (Hold till shakes, and click x).

The simulator also has a 'Clear data and settings' option in the 'iPhone simulator' menu

Answer (score 0):

While I don't recommend this way, but it's good to know.

Each app stores it's data on the harddisk in your Documents. The easiest way to find the directory for your current app is to save some document using the app, let's say *abc123.png* and then search your harddisk for that document.

There you will find all the data saved by this app. I use this way when I want to clear all data of said app and then rebuild it all.